# How to use Expectation maximization to estimate poisson noise matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab, approximation

I delved into the state of the art of algorithms for Poisson noise estimation in order to estimate the variance, I found that the Expectation Maximization algorithm is very used and it is very effective and easy to use,

But I have not found the matlab code, I found only one that is was used for classification,

can you give me the code or the algorithm for estimating and not for classification please.

I would be grateful if you answer me

Comment: What do you mean by poisson noise estimation? Poisson parameter $\lambda$ is estimated using the sample mean.

Comment: @Hasan Poisson noise estimation mean estimating the level of the noise (variance sigma) in the image

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18813068/427252

Answer (score 1):

Explanations of the Expectation Maximisation algorithm:

[Nature.com ( Nature Biotechnology 26, 897 - 899 (2008) )](http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v26/n8/full/nbt1406.html)

[Wikipedia - Expectation–maximization algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm)

[Stack Overflow - What is an intuitive explanation of Expectation Maximization technique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808074/what-is-an-intuitive-explanation-of-expectation-maximization-technique)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the links you provided, but I see that they are theoretical aspect, in addition very complicated for me with all the formulas :(

I want to know the following information: if the EM algorithm can estimate  the variance of poissoniien noise

Is it possible to provide me matlab  a link matlab pleasssseee